# Facebook shared url not showing image

Tags: image, facebook, share

We've created quite simple contest application.
As a result each user receives individual page with possibility of sharing final post (and image):
https://polskibus.frogriot.com/konkurs/186-9872ed9fc22fc182d371c3e9ed316094/

The problem is that for each post shared we have this weird behaviour that image is visible on general facebook news feed, also visible on iphone facebook app but not visible on my timeline:
https://scr.hu/3D7yyL

The page we are sharing has proper og: tags set. Also we are precaching the image twice using facebook debugger scraps. In facebook debugger link looks ok. And we run out of ideas on how to fix it :/ Any help appreciated.

Comment: It works ok in my tests, so i'd suggest at this point it's likely a "local" issue, have you tried from different browsers, computers, cleared cache, incognito/private mode, also try viewing your timeline from another account?

Comment: The issue is more complicated - when you go through form (which is in polish): https://polskibus.frogriot.com/ in the end you would receive your indvidual link and image to share and when you share this new URL you may or may not see the problem. It's possible that facebook have properly cached my previously posted link and it works now.

Comment: Also we are testing by several people, different accounts, browsers, location (and connections) and can't find any common pattern :/

Comment: Sometimes while sharing you might have blank post although it's twice scrapped for facebook :/ https://scr.hu/GVKp1y